# Cannot find custom fields that are part of an installed package in Tooling API object 'CustomField'

Tags: soql, custom-field, tooling-api, installedpackage

I'm trying to find out which object (using the Tooling API) stores custom fields for installed packages. I've downloaded all custom fields from this object: 'CustomField' for the Contact object:

```
SELECT Id,DeveloperName,CreatedDate,CreatedById,Description,EntityDefinitionId,InlineHelpText,LastModifiedById,LastModifiedDate,Length,ManageableState,MaskChar,MaskType,NamespacePrefix,Precision,RelationshipLabel,Scale,SummaryOperation,TableEnumOrId FROM CustomField WHERE TableEnumOrId = 'Contact'
```

But only has 378 records and does not contain custom fields that are part of an installed package e.g. Cloudingo - can anyone tell me the object name please?

I've tried searching in here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm for 'installed package' and 'installedpackage' but cant find anything and there is soo many objects, im lost.

Thank you for your time all.

Comment: I'm also looking for the object that holds which Profiles have access to fields - 'Visible' 'Read-Only' information please. *The information you get from the UI if you go to a field and click on 'Set Field-Level Security' and then it lists all the Profiles and access level.

Comment: Rich, don't you see any records with NamespacePrefix using your CustomField query? What do you get as a result from this Tooling API query: `SELECT COUNT(Id),NamespacePrefix 
FROM CustomField 
WHERE NamespacePrefix!=null 
GROUP BY NamespacePrefix`

Comment: Ah, thank you Felix, got it now. Do you also know which object holds the Profile level access data to fields - Visible and Ready Only please?